# Can't get rid of SVN project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have a project ProjectA in Eclipse that is checkout through `SVN`. What I want to do is remove this SVN project locally and create a new, purely local project *also* called ProjectA. So I disconnect first, then delete locally, then try to create a new ProjectA. However upon creating this project the connection re-opens!

Comment: How are you deleting the project?

Comment: @greg-449 Right click delete

Comment: Did you check the _Delete project contents on disk_ box when deleting?

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the project in you file explorer / outside of eclipse and delete all the `.svn` folders. If you are using svn 1.7 client or above then you're lucky and have only one folder in the first level of your working copy, otherwise you'll have to delete that folder from each sub directory in your working copy.

Import the project back to eclipse as java project.